# Error message during g++ compiling an installation file

Tags: gcc, boost, g++

The environments are Cent OS 6.7, boost-1.6.2, gcc-6.2.0

I have tried to install a software, but I got some errors.
Are theses errors come from g++ ? or boost?
I can't understand these messages.. because I have never been use g++..

Here is starting line.

```
[root@cms CASMcode-0.2.0]# scons install
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
rm /usr/local/include/casm
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
Install directory: "include/casm" as "/usr/local/include/casm"
/usr/local/gcc-6.2/bin/g++-6.2 -o src/casm/version/version.os -c -DNDEBUG -O3 --std=c++11 -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-deprecated-declarations -DEIGEN_DEFAULT_DENSE_INDEX_TYPE=long -Wno-unused-parameter -DNDEBUG -O3 -DGZSTREAM_NAMESPACE=gz -fPIC -Iinclude src/casm/version/version.cc
/usr/local/gcc-6.2/bin/g++-6.2 -o src/casm/clex/ConfigIOStrucScore.os -c -DNDEBUG -O3 --std=c++11 -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-deprecated-declarations -DEIGEN_DEFAULT_DENSE_INDEX_TYPE=long -Wno-unused-parameter -DNDEBUG -O3 -DGZSTREAM_NAMESPACE=gz -fPIC -Iinclude -I/usr/local/boost_1_62_0/include src/casm/clex/ConfigIOStrucScore.cc
In file included from include/casm/external/Eigen/Core:263:0,
                 from include/casm/external/Eigen/Dense:1,
                 from include/casm/CASM_global_definitions.hh:13,
                 from include/casm/casm_io/EigenDataStream.hh:3,
                 from src/casm/clex/ConfigIOStrucScore.cc:3:
```

Error message appear here.

```
In file included from include/casm/casm_io/DataFormatterTools.hh:1291:0,
                 from include/casm/casm_io/DataFormatter_impl.hh:3,
                 from include/casm/casm_io/DataFormatter.hh:757,
                 from include/casm/clex/ConfigIO.hh:4,
                 from src/casm/clex/ConfigIOStrucScore.cc:6:
include/casm/casm_io/DataFormatterTools_impl.hh: In member function 'bool CASM::DataFormatterOperator<ValueType, ArgType, DataObject>::parse_args(const string&)':
include/casm/casm_io/DataFormatterTools_impl.hh:33:33: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const wstring& {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t>&}' from expression of type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
             val = std::stod(ttag);
                                 ^
```

And here

```
In file included from include/casm/clex/PrimClex.hh:14:0,
                 from include/casm/clex/ConfigIOStrucScore.hh:6,
                 from src/casm/clex/ConfigIOStrucScore.cc:7:
include/casm/clex/ChemicalReference.hh: In member function 'void CASM::ChemicalReferencePrinter::print(const std::vector<CASM::ChemicalReferenceState>&)':
include/casm/clex/ChemicalReference.hh:366:27: error: 'round' is not a member of 'std'
           if(almost_equal(std::round(num), num, 1e-14)) {
                           ^~~
```

Comment: You should upgrade your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Current version is 6.2 and has a much better support of recent C++ standards.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks, I upgraded gcc to 6.2 but the error still happen at a different file. `At global scope:
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-deprecated-register'
scons: *** [src/casm/crystallography/Lattice.os] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.`

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot help you, especially if you are not familiar with C++11. This is not a *fix-my-code* forum. If you are familiar with C++11, the error messages should be meaningful enough. If you are not familiar with C++11, you'll need perhaps a year of work to learn it. Start by reading http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/ ; but it looks like your issue is not specific to the compiler. You could use a recent [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) but you still are likely to get errors.

Comment: BTW, Current version of [boost](http://www.boost.org/) is 1.62, so you also need to upgrade it.

Comment: I find your paths (e.g. `/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2`) incredibly weird. Perhaps you forgot some installation step (e.g. some `make install`) for some of the components or tools that you are using, or perhaps you gave bad arguments at `configure` time (sometimes `--prefix` or `--program-suffix` are useful, but YMMV). It looks that you messed up your system.

Comment: Yes it was a my mistake. So I installed gcc-6.2.0 and Clang/LLVM but the errors related to `std::` functions still exist. Are theses errors came from version problem? I edited the main text.